# Core Data - awakeFromFetch() called on descendant of deleted object after save context

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

#### The Setup

I have the following entities in Core Data:

`Project` <->> `Sheet` <->> `Attachment`

*(Actual class names changed. Each project is the parent to many sheets, and each sheet is the parent to many attachments.)*

Both relationships are configured to "Cascade" towards the children (the to-many direction) and "Nullify" towards the parent (the to-one direction).

The leaf entity `Attachment` holds external image data that is not managed by core data: instead, it is stored in the file system and only the file path is stored in a managed property.

On startup, my app checks the total disk space used by the images associated with the `Attachment` entities, and if it is above a certain threshold it deletes  *projects* (therefore *sheets* therefore *attachments*, because: cascade) in order from oldest to newest.

#### The Immediate Cause for The Crash

After deleting the projects, I save the context and that somehow triggers `awakeFromFetch()` on the `Attachment` instances.

Inside `awakeFromFetch()`, the Attachment class retreives the locally saved image data. The path is built using the parent objects' (custom) unique identifiers, like:

`/Caches/Projects/<Project ID>/Sheets/<Sheet ID>/Attachments/<Attachment ID>/image.jpg`

**However,** my app crashes when the `Attachment` in question, in order to build the file path above, references the parent `Sheet` and this in turn tries to reference its parent `Project` (which has just been deleted). Sounds like the cascade rule is not working. Also, why are the grandchildren being fetched when I save after deleting the grandparent?

The call stack at the moment of the crash looks something like this: (some method names changed, some intermediate methods skipped)

```
Thread 1 Queue: com.apple.main-thread (serial)
   0 specialized _assertionFailed(StaticString, String, StaticString, UInt) -> ()
   1 MyStorageManager.(subdirectory in _XXXX...
   2 MyStorageManager.imageForAttachment(attachment) -> UIImage?
   3 Attachment.awakeFromFetch()
   ---------------------------
   18 -[NSMangedObjectContext save:]
   19 MyStorageManager.cleanup()
   20 AppDelegate.init() -> AppDelegate
   ---------------------------
   23 UIApplicationMain
   24 main
   25 start
```

**Curiously**, my UI (a table view) has an alternative way of manually deleting each `Project` instance, and this does not trigger the crash. In particular, `Attachment.awakeFromFetch()` is not called when saving the context after deletion in this case.

Moving the cleanup code from `AppDelegate.init()` to `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` does not make a difference...

Comment: You removed the interesting part of the call stack. What is Core Data doing in stack frame 4 - 17?

Comment: They aren' there, I didn't remove anything. It skips like that.